# Unable to fetch tab id from sub tab in Jquery

Tags: jquery, tabs

I am using a tab structure as below:

```
<div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#dia_details">Details</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab_raise_req">Raise Req</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="dia_details">
            <div id="sub_tabs">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#DIA_details">DIA Details</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#allocate_ba">Allocate BA</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="DIA_details>
                    <form>
                    --Code--
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div id="allocate_ba">
                    <form>
                    --Code--
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tab_raise_req">
            <form>
                --Code--
            </form>
        </div>
```

When I am in a sub tab and want to save the particular tab for which I have defined a button, I wanted to obtain the tab id of the currently active tab.....which is one of the sub tabs.

For this I was using the below function in Jquery:

```
// Save Changes button click
$("#save_changes_id").click(function() {
    //  To retrieve the current TAB and assign it to a variable ...
    var curTab = $('.ui-tabs-active'); 
    var curTabPanelId = curTab.find("a").attr("href");
    responseData = doAjaxCall($(curTabPanelId + " form"));
    if(responseData == 1) 
        showMessage('status_msg', 'Project details updated successfully', 'green');
    else
        showMessage('status_msg', 'Error: Please check all the fields', 'red');
});
```

Here the function is returning the id of the parent tab instead of the sub tab. I tried using addClass and removeClass but of no use.

Please suggest a solution for this. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Probably debug and check $('.ui-tabs-active') return how many elements. It might be returning two elements, one parent and another sub. try alert($('.ui-tabs-active').length)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('.ui-tabs-active')` will find two divs, the parent and sub-tab. Try using `$('.ui-tabs-active:last')` to get the lowest level tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
    var curTab = $('#sub_tabs .ui-tabs-active');
```